# sample a dataframe based on priority

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
import random
import pandas as pd
col1 = random.choices([1,2,3,4,5],k=50)
col2 = random.choices(['A','B','C'],k=50)
df = pd.DataFrame({'values':col1,'priority':col2})
```

I want to pull a sample of 25, but if 25 have priority 'A', I want those 25. if 30 have priority 'A', I want 25 chosen from that 30. if 20 have priority 'A', I want those 20, and a random 5 from the 30 with priority 'B'. If 10 have priority 'A' and 10 have priority 'B', I want all 10 'A' and all 10 'B', and 5 random 'C'.

The only way I can think to do this is split the dataset into 3, and then use if statements like

```
if len(df_A) ==25:
    output = df_A
elif len(df_A) >25:
    output = df_A.sample(n=25)
elif len(df_A) + len(df_B) == 25:
    output = pd.concat([df_A,df_b])
```

and so on.
Is there a better way to do this? possibly something that scales up to a larger number of priority groups?

Comment: I just had the idea to randomize the dataframe, then use sort and take the top 25 of the dataframe.  I think this will work.

Comment: `df.sample(frac=1).sort_values(by='priority').head(25)`